# Unable to delete a record from a flat file c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, flat-file

I am trying to delete specific line from a text file using c# as:

```
 public static void DeleteProject(int id)
    {
        var fileloc = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FFProject-Manager"];

        var fileloc2 = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempFile"];

        string line = null;

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileloc))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileloc2))
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string uidCompare = Convert.ToString(line.Split(',')[0]);
                    string uidToCompare = Convert.ToString(id);
                    if (String.Compare(uidCompare, uidToCompare) == 0)
                        continue;

                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }

            }

        }

        File.Delete(fileloc);
        File.Move(fileloc2, fileloc);
    }

}
```

But when I try to execute it gives the error as:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Flat_Files\Project-Manager.txt' because it is being used by another process.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is it the move or delete that is throwing the error?

Comment: File.Delete(fileloc);  is throwing error

Comment: reader must be close before delete a file.

Comment: I did that too but no change.. I tried reader.Dispose(); too

Comment: By default asp.net process has permission for App_Data to write but not modify files. I.e. you can create new files but cannot modify them (delete, move). I similar problem with logger: it looked like logger worked but until it archived old logs. I took time to understand that problem was missing 'modify' permission for folder, 'write' is not enough. Check folder permissions.

Comment: Which process is locking the file? See http://superuser.com/questions/117902/easy-way-to-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: No process is blocking my file.I also modified the permissions but the problem still persists